# How to define and access private and protected variables and functions in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I am confused in accessing private variables in `python3` because it makes new variable if access it from a wrong way. I made a private variable `_data` (Single underscore. Right?) in a class and I want to access it in child class.

```
class A_parent:
      _myVar=0


class B_child:
      _myVar=_myVar+1    #Right or wrong?
```

What is the convention of `private, protected modifier` in `python3`?

Answer (score 0):

Simple underscore is just a convention to discourage callers/users of the variable: your example will work (except that you probably want to define an instance variable, not a class variable)

To make variable private you have to use double underscore BUT:

```
class A_parent:
      __myVar=0


class B_child(A_parent):
      __myVar=__myVar+1    # __myVar or A and B are different: error because right term is not defined yet.
```

you are talking of "kind of protected" variables. In that case, it is advised to use simple underscore like you did.

Example for an instance variable, much more useful:

```
class A_parent:
    def __init__(self):
       self._myVar=0


class B_child(A_parent):
     def __init__(self):
      # call parent constructor else _myVar isn't defined
      A_parent.__init__(self)
      # syntax using super
      # super(B_child, self).__init__()

      self._myVar+=1    # Okay
```

If you REALLY want to access the private parent attribute, you can do this:

```
class A_parent:
    def __init__(self):
       self.__myVar=12


class B_child(A_parent):
     def __init__(self):
      # call parent constructor
      A_parent.__init__(self)
      print(self._A_parent__myVar)  # will print 12 when class is instantiated
```

but of course it's ill-advised. Use only when you can't refactor the mother class. I never had to do that.

Note that if you omit the call to the parent constructor, `self._A_parent__myVar` won't be defined
(Python is a dynamic language: you define members on the fly. In C++ or Java, not invoking the constructor would still define parent member variables, but not here)

Comment: In case of Double underscore- How  to access it ?

Comment: What this line is `A_parent.__init__(self)` doing? Is it calling the parent constructor? Is it compulsory? But passing the parent class in child `class B_child(A_parent):`  will not fulfill the requirement?

Comment: it is recommended! or you break Liskov principe and in your case the variable is not defined.